# how to count number of words for each column which is in array structure in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, word-count

I have the string column in my dataframe, where I have split the sentences into words. Now I need to calculate the occurrence of that word and converting them to columns. Basically creating a document term matrix

```
0                   [kubernetes, client, bootstrapping, ponda]
1                                                [micro, insu]
2                                                 [motor, upi]
3                                  [secure, app, installation]
4                    [health, insu, express, credit, customer]
5                                  [secure, app, installation]
6                                                 [aap, insta]
7                               [loan, house, loan, customers]
```

Output :

```
    kubernetes  client  bootstrapping   ponda   loan    customers   installation
0        1       1      1               1       0           0        0
1        0       0      0               0       1           0        1
2        0       2      0               0       0           0        0
3        1       1      1               1       0           0        0
```

Code so far

```
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

 countvec = CountVectorizer()

 countvec.fit_transform(df.new)
```

Error :

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `CountVectorizer` the way you've used it, you need your DataFrame to be like this:

```
                                  string
0  kubernetes client bootstrapping ponda
1                             micro insu
2                              motor upi
3                secure app installation
4    health insu express credit customer
5                secure app installation
6                              aap insta
7              loan house loan customers
```

At the moment, you have it like this:

```
                                   stringList
0  [kubernetes, client, bootstrapping, ponda]
1                               [micro, insu]
2                                [motor, upi]
3                 [secure, app, installation]
4   [health, insu, express, credit, customer]
5                 [secure, app, installation]
6                                [aap, insta]
7              [loan, house, loan, customers]
```

So here's how you go about transforming it in the way it's required for you to use `CountVectorizer`

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[['kubernetes', 'client', 'bootstrapping', 'ponda']], [['micro', 'insu']], [['motor', 'upi']],[['secure', 'app', 'installation']],[['health', 'insu', 'express', 'credit', 'customer']],[['secure', 'app', 'installation']],[['aap', 'insta']],[['loan', 'house', 'loan', 'customers']]])

df.columns = ['new']
```

I'm calling your column which has the list of words as `new` like how it originally is in your DataFrame.

```
df['string'] = ""
```

I'm creating an empty column, where I will concatenate each word in that list of words.

```
for i in df.index:

    df.at[i, 'string'] = " ".join(item for item in df.at[i, 'new'])
```

I've scanned by row, and concatenated each item in the list of strings with a `" "`, and added it to the `string` column.

```
df.drop(['new'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Now, the column with the list of string is not needed! so I'm dropping it.

NOW your DataFrame is ready in the way you want it! Now you can use `CountVectorizer`!

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

countvec = CountVectorizer()

counts = countvec.fit_transform(df['string'])

vocab = pd.DataFrame(counts.toarray())
vocab.columns = countvec.get_feature_names()

print(vocab)
```

Gives

```
   aap  app  bootstrapping  client  credit  customer  customers  express  \
0    0    0              1       1       0         0          0        0   
1    0    0              0       0       0         0          0        0   
2    0    0              0       0       0         0          0        0   
3    0    1              0       0       0         0          0        0   
4    0    0              0       0       1         1          0        1   
5    0    1              0       0       0         0          0        0   
6    1    0              0       0       0         0          0        0   
7    0    0              0       0       0         0          1        0   

   health  house  insta  installation  insu  kubernetes  loan  micro  motor  \
0       0      0      0             0     0           1     0      0      0   
1       0      0      0             0     1           0     0      1      0   
2       0      0      0             0     0           0     0      0      1   
3       0      0      0             1     0           0     0      0      0   
4       1      0      0             0     1           0     0      0      0   
5       0      0      0             1     0           0     0      0      0   
6       0      0      1             0     0           0     0      0      0   
7       0      1      0             0     0           0     2      0      0   

   ponda  secure  upi  
0      1       0    0  
1      0       0    0  
2      0       0    1  
3      0       1    0  
4      0       0    0  
5      0       1    0  
6      0       0    0  
7      0       0    0
```

Comment: @Anagha Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If values are lists first [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) them together and then use `CountVectorizer`:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'new']))
<class 'list'>

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

countvec = CountVectorizer()
counts = countvec.fit_transform(df['new'].str.join(' '))
df = pd.DataFrame(counts.toarray(), columns=countvec.get_feature_names())
```

---

Another pandas solution with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and `sum`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['new'].values.tolist())
df = pd.get_dummies(df1, prefix='', prefix_sep='').sum(axis=1, level=0)
```

---

```
print (df)

   aap  app  bootstrapping  client  credit  customer  customers  express  \
0    0    0              1       1       0         0          0        0   
1    0    0              0       0       0         0          0        0   
2    0    0              0       0       0         0          0        0   
3    0    1              0       0       0         0          0        0   
4    0    0              0       0       1         1          0        1   
5    0    1              0       0       0         0          0        0   
6    1    0              0       0       0         0          0        0   
7    0    0              0       0       0         0          1        0   

   health  house  insta  installation  insu  kubernetes  loan  micro  motor  \
0       0      0      0             0     0           1     0      0      0   
1       0      0      0             0     1           0     0      1      0   
2       0      0      0             0     0           0     0      0      1   
3       0      0      0             1     0           0     0      0      0   
4       1      0      0             0     1           0     0      0      0   
5       0      0      0             1     0           0     0      0      0   
6       0      0      1             0     0           0     0      0      0   
7       0      1      0             0     0           0     2      0      0   

   ponda  secure  upi  
0      1       0    0  
1      0       0    0  
2      0       0    1  
3      0       1    0  
4      0       0    0  
5      0       1    0  
6      0       0    0  
7      0       0    0
```

Comment: Ya, then use first solution.

Comment: In my answer are 2 solutions :)